# Get Incremental number using partition by In mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have Some unique scenario

**Input:**

```
   VAR
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   NULL
5   NULL
6   A
7   A
8   A
9   B
10  B
11  B
12  NULL
13  B
14  B
15  B
16  C
17  C
18  C
19  C
```

I have input data in above order. I need to create output column as Rank using partition column VAR. But if there is null in between it Rank should get reset its counter.

**Expected Output:**

```
   VAR  output
1   A   1
2   A   2
3   A   3
4   NULL    
5   NULL    
6   A   1
7   A   2
8   A   3
9   B   1
10  B   2
11  B   3
12  NULL    
13  B   1
14  B   2
15  B   3
16  C   1
17  C   2
18  C   3
19  C   4
```

Comment: *I have input data in above order*: not really, unless you have another column that defines the ordering of records.

Comment: @GMB I have Index column for ordering, check now updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a gaps and islands problem. Assuming that you have another column that defines the ordering of the records (say, `id`), here is an approach that uses the difference between row numbers to define the groups of adjacent records:

```
select 
    var,
    case when var is not null
        then row_number() over(partition by var, rn1 - rn2 order by id) 
    end rnk 
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by id) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by var order by id) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
order by id
```

Note that window functions are available in latest MySQL version only (that is, version 8.0).